# Why a path to a file retrieved from an external file with tail, doesn't work as argument for a program launched from a bash script

Tags: bash

This is the last line I retrieve with tail from a file named ./config2.cfg located in the same directory as my bash script:

```
LastUsedROM = /media/user1/MIYOO/Roms/MD/Golden Axe II (World).zip
```

And this is my bash script, from where I retrieve the said line with tail (on line 3, I remove the "LastUsedROM = " part I don't need):

```
#!/bin/bash
LASTSAVED=$( tail -n 1 ./config2.cfg )
LASTSAVED=${LASTSAVED:14}
mednafen "$LASTSAVED"
```

And it doesn't work...

However, if I do that:

```
#!/bin/bash
LASTSAVED="LastUsedROM = /media/user1/MIYOO/Roms/MD/Golden Axe II (World).zip"
LASTSAVED=${LASTSAVED:14}
mednafen "$LASTSAVED"
```

It works...

Why? What am I doing wrong? It doesn't make sense, I'm starting to get crazy over this...

Edit:

```
#!/bin/bash
LASTSAVED=$( tail -n 1 ./config2.cfg )
LASTSAVED=${LASTSAVED:14}

LASTSAVEDD="LastUsedROM = /media/user1/MIYOO/Roms/MD/Golden Axe II (World).zip"
LASTSAVEDD=${LASTSAVEDD:14}

echo $LASTSAVED
echo $LASTSAVEDD

#mednafen "$LASTSAVED"
```

In the script above, "echo $LASTSAVED" and "echo $LASTSAVEDD" both respectively return:

/media/user1/MIYOO/Roms/MD/Golden Axe II (World).zip

/media/user1/MIYOO/Roms/MD/Golden Axe II (World).zip

Edit2:

So it turns out @Shawn was right, so the final script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#LASTSAVED=$(tail -n1 ./config2.cfg)
LASTSAVED=$(sed '$!d' ./config2.cfg)
LASTSAVED=${LASTSAVED:14}
LASTSAVED=${LASTSAVED//[$'\t\r\n']}
mednafen "$LASTSAVED"
```

I ended up using sed instead of tail, because on the final device (powkiddy v90) where that bit of script is going to run, bash isn't available, only sh is, and tail doesn't seem to with it. And on line 5 I trim the LASTSAVED string in order to remove the additional carriage return generated by the picodrive emulator in the ./config2.cfg file (I used mednafen for testing purpose on my dev machine)

Thx Shawn

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean? (I bet it's a line ending issue)

Comment: Did you check if `tail -n 1 ./config2.cfg` from the command line produces the expected line? As @Shawn said, it may be line ending issue in the file.

Comment: Running with libsndfile-1.0.31
 Base directory: /home/user1/.mednafen
 Emulation modules: apple2 nes snes gb gba pce lynx md pcfx ngp psx ss ssfplay vb wswan sms gg snes_faust pce_fast demo cdplay
 Opening lockfile...
 Loading settings from "/home/user1/.mednafen/mednafen.cfg"...
  Loaded 7544 valid settings and 0 unknown settings.
 Initializing joysticks...
...ading /media/user1/MIYOO/Roms/MD/Golden Axe II (World).zip
": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type/Roms/MD/Golden Axe II (World).zip

Comment: @Ashok yes I did, echo $LASTSAVED returns the exact same string in both cases (/media/user1/MIYOO/Roms/MD/Golden Axe II (World).zip) and the last line in ./config2.cfg is the very last line with no extra character no nothing

Comment: @Shawn I opened ./config2.cfg with "visual studio code" instead of "xed text editor" and it turns out that, that in visual studio there were 65 lines, while in xed there were 64... So you were right